# Is it possible to inject a property through autowired when that bean already has another property set through xml

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I'm trying to define a bean.

```
<bean id="prop1" class="Prop1"/>

<bean id="myBean" class="myClass">
    <property name="prop2">
        <bean class="Prop2">
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now I have this class

```
public class myClass(){
    @Autowired
    private Prop1 prop1;
    private Prop2 prop2;

    public setProp2(Prop2 prop2){
        this.prop2 = prop2;
    }
    ...
}
```

Im aware that I can just add property to myBean bean but I am trying to avoid that. Right now im getting null on prop1. Is it possible to initialized `prop1`? If not please explain or give me a link to read about this.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should just work. It is probably not working because you are likely missing a `AutowiredAnnotationPostProcessor`, which is a bean post processor responsible for wiring in `@Autowired` dependencies. You can get it by just adding these to the xml config file:

```
<context:annoation-config/>
```

Or

```
<context:component-scan/>
```